# Ionic - Custom Android wrapper

Tags: android, webview, ionic-framework

I'm building an `Ionic` application and I need to pack it into a custom `Android wrapper`. Basically, it's a simple `WebView` linked to a downloader. Everytime it is possible, the app checks if there is any update and download the `Ionic souces` to a local directory.

The downloader works perfectly but I got an issue when I need to load the local website into the `WebView`. So far, here is my code:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{
    webSettings.setDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath() + "databases/");
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
{
    webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

// Attach listeners
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains(Constants.END_POINT) || Uri.parse(url).getScheme().contains("file")) return false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        layout_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback)
    {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
});

// Attach javascript interface
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WrapperJSInterface(this, webview), "Wrapper");

// Load index
String index = "/data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#"
webview.loadUrl("file://" + index);
```

The `WebView` loads to a white page but it throws some errors like these:

```
12-01 15:26:47.793: E/Web Console(8931): Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined at file:///data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#/app/feed:1
12-01 15:26:47.808: E/Web Console(8931): Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined at file:///data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#/app/feed:2
12-01 15:26:47.808: E/Web Console(8931): Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined at file:///data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#/app/feed:3
12-01 15:26:47.808: E/Web Console(8931): Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined at file:///data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#/app/feed:4
12-01 15:26:47.808: E/Web Console(8931): Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined at file:///data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#/app/feed:5
12-01 15:26:47.808: E/Web Console(8931): Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined at file:///data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#/app/feed:6
```

I've investigated and found some people have encountered the same issue. But I wasn't able to fix it.
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/uncaught-referenceerror-addrow-is-not-defined/9266

If this can help, I'm **NOT** using `Cordova` in any way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The "Web Console" errors are Javascript errors in the files you are loading.  Given that the files appear to be embedded in your app, it should be within your power to correct those errors.

Comment: The error doesn't occur while running the app directly in the `Chrome browser` or on my computer.

Comment: You do realize that your `index` begins with `/` and then you're prepending `file://`, for a result of `file:///data...`?

Comment: The files are located in the `/data/data/com.my.wrapper/` directory, so I think this is legitimate to have a `/` right after `file://`. Let me try it without but I don't think this will go well. **EDIT: Sorry, it doesn't work.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy.

I simply changed

`String index = "/data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/#"`

to

`String index = "/data/data/com.my.wrapper/files/index.html"`